# How can we create new char at c#.Net console?

Tags: c#, console, char, game-development

How can we create new char for using into Console in order to we create a simple game with it,for example we can  import some char of char map app to console and my question is how can we create specific own char.another my question is how can we clear a special position of console not whole console buffer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. What you asking for is unclear. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.I want to creat a simple game like River Raid 1982 Atari in console of .Net. as you know we can't use pixel or graph method inside console so We must simulate graphic objects. Now my question is how can we do this without using graphics and create our own characters and display them on the console.

Comment: You can't, as I know. The windows modern console has less functionnalities that the old dos console. You can't plot sprites, patterns, chars... on it. But you can try using specials chars to move, erase, draw... I don't know if it will work. You can use a Form and GDI+.

Comment: The easiest way to clear portions of the console is to set the cursor position and then write spaces where you want to clear. You can get finer control by calling the Windows Console API directly, but it gets kind of messy. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions for the gory details.

Comment: You mean I use win32 method,well can we extend the console ourselves?like adding extension methods or writing unsafe code

Comment: Yes, you can extend the console. I have some code, http://www.mischel.com/consoledotnet/consoledotnet.zip, that you're free to use. Be aware, I wrote that back in 2006 and haven't used it in some years. So there's no guarantee that it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As people have stated, it is probably impossible to make any sort of functioning game in a Console Application with a user interface (although I've seen the Super Mario theme song being re-created, too). Nevertheless, people who are aiming to do games (such as the the River Raid 1982 game you've mentioned) tend to utilise software such as Unity, UnReal Engine, etc, as they are the best platforms for doing so.

I would recommend looking at some tutorials for Unity etc, if that is what you want.